# Java8 NIO Stream > More efficient way to recursively retrieve directory sizes?

Tags: java, recursion

For a given directory, I'm attempting to recursively retrieve each directory's size (in the most efficient way possible). I wanted to make use of the Java8 NIO Streams if possible (for speed & efficiency), but would settle with a 3rd party library (why re-invent the wheel).

For example, it would be more efficient to iterate through the directories depth-first, summing the child file/prev-calculated-directory sizes as we move up through each level. My current solution is inefficient, in that it re-calculates the directory size, starting from the top level.

Any library suggestions/code samples/guidance would be greatly appreciated...

**Current solution:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

public class DirectorySizes {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // retrieve map of path -> size...
        Map<Path, Long> directorySize = Files.walk(Paths.get("/tmp"))
                .filter(Files::isDirectory)
                .collect(toMap(Path::toAbsolutePath, DirectorySizes::getDirectorySize));
        // print {size} {directory}...
        directorySize.entrySet().forEach(e ->
                System.out.printf("%15s  %s %n", e.getValue(), e.getKey())
        );
    }

    public static long getDirectorySize(Path path) {
        try {
            return Files.walk(path).filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                    .mapToLong(DirectorySizes::getFileSize).sum();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static long getFileSize(Path file) {
        try {
            return Files.size(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

**Sample output:**

```
       2812  C:\tmp\foobar\static\css 
       6936  C:\tmp\foobar\static 
       7821  C:\tmp\foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of changes that might help:

- Your `FileVisitor` is passed a `BasicFileAttributes` which includes the size of the file. You don't need to recalculate it with `Files.size`.
- [walkFileTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.util.Set-int-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-) is already depth first. You should be able to collect size info to collate as you walk the tree